# SSRS Filtering By NULL from another column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have two columns:

1. Patient_List
2. Patient_ID

I need to isolate all records in Patient_ID where the Patient_List Column is NULL (NULL = Blank Record)

How do I filter by null values in the Patient_List that I can return the needed records in on the Patient_ID column? I can't find anything that explains how to identify NULL/Blank Columns in SSRS DAX code.

Comment: What I usually do in this instance is substatute the NULL value in both the parameter list and the report dataset. Then you'll be able to filter for the NULLs. I usually use something like "<NULL>" so it sorts to the top.

Comment: I had to go back into my SQL code and create a case column where all NULL instances = 0 and everything else = 1. I was then able to filter on that new column where all instances = 0. It solved the problem for me, but I am still not sure if there is a way to address NULL values beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to figure out how to filter by a NULL value in SSRS. But I was able to go back into my SQL code and create a case column where all NULL instances = 0 and everything else = 1. I was then able to filter on that new column where all instances = 0, with the SSRS table filtering feature.